# Facebook Login button in Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new for Android.

I have tried the code below using facebook's javascript SDK. It works fine.
But how to use the code below in Android app at index.html?

For the Android app, I have imported facebook's Android SDK as a library project in Eclipse.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'myAppId',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
     alert('Thanks for logging in'); 
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML ='Not authorized';
    }
  });
}
</script>

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_friends,read_friendlists" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>

<div id="status"></div>
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your javascript code into your android code by Binding javascript code to android code.

By calling this **addJavascriptInterface()**

before that enable javascript in webview by calling **setJavaScriptEnabled()**.

this following page help you to bind your Javascript code to Android.  See **Binding Javascript code to Android Code** section.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Thats all..